# How to prevent CALL query disconnecting from database?

Tags: php, mysqli

In my search engine I have to do this line:

```
$qresult = mysqli_query($db, "CALL get_urls('$input[0]');") or die('error');
```

Multiple times. Is it normal that it stops the database connection? Is there a way around it, or I'll have to do

```
$db = mysqli_connect();
```

After every CALL query?

Comment: It should not close the connection, unless you're running `mysqli_close()`

Comment: No, it's not normal. It sounds like the database server is crashing, so maybe there's a problem in the function that kills the server.

Comment: Check your MySQL server log to see if it's crashing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so, if you want to call multiple procedures, you need to put

```
mysqli_next_result($database);
```

Dunno what it does and why do you want to do that, but it helps.